# How to group by day archives on rails blog?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails, just finished Michael Hartl's tutorial.

I am creating a small blog as my first app, I am looking to sort all the homepage blog posts and group them by.

example: TODAY and all today's post...below that YESTERDAY and yesterday's posts, etc.

I see there is a method called group_by but can't figure out how to implement it

Can someone help?
See many people are looking for such a solution online.

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: are you going to list the items in each group ? or just show counts ?

Answer (score 1):

There's an awesome gem for this [groupdate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate), try it out, a sample code below

```
Blog.group_by_day(:created_at)
```

https://github.com/ankane/groupdate

Comment: Yes , saw the gem but it won't explain how to render in the posts index view ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group_by`

```
posts = posts.group_by{|post|
      case post.created_at
          when 0.days.ago..1.day.ago
            "Today"
          when 1.day.ago..2.days.ago
            "Yesterday"
          when 1.week.ago..2.weeks.ago
            "Last week"
          when 2.weeks.ago..3.weeks.ago
            "2 weeks ago"
          when 1.month.ago..2.months.ago
            "Last month"
          else
            "Older"
          end
}
```

**EDIT**

Above code will return you as Hash, in view

```
@posts = {"Older"=>[#<Contact id: 1, name: "sontya", email: "montya@mailinator.com", comments: "hi there", created_at: "2015-03-20 
16:46:52", updated_at: "2015-03-20 16:46:52">, #<Contact id: 2, name: "faruk", email: "faruk@dispostable.com", comments: "hi there", created_at:
"2015-03-23 18:17:05", updated_at: "2015-03-23 18:17:05">],   "Yesterday" => [#<Contact id: 1, name: "sontya", email:    
"montya@mailinator.com", comments: "hi there", created_at: "2015-03-20 16:46:52", updated_at: "2015-03-20 16:46:52">, #<Contact id: 2, name:
"faruk", email: "faruk@dispostable.com", comments: "hi there", created_at: "2015-03-23 18:17:05", updated_at: "2015-03-23 18:17:05">]}
```

similar to this with your data, then
in view, loop through the `Hash`

```
<% @posts.each do |k,v| %>
   <tr>
      <td><%=k%></td>
   </tr>
   <% v.each do |post| %>
      <tr>
         <td><%=post.name%></td>
      </tr>  
   <% end %>  
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was doing but got stuck in how to render it in the posts index view?

Comment: Once I post what you mentioned on the controller I don't know what to put on the view, didn't know how to start putting it so no code to show.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a database level group isn't correct, because it's usually used with sum or count or something like that, if you don't use any of those functions that applies on groups you'll end up with only one post for each group, which is in your case one post for each day, I think you should just select all and group them into arrays and loop in the view

```
posts = Post.some_home_page_query.order(:created_at)
@grouped_posts = posts.chunk{ |x| x.created_at.to_date }

# you can replace the block passed to chunk with whatever you
# see fit for your own case
```

In the view you could do something like this

```
- @grouped_posts.each |date, posts|
  = "Posts for #{date.some_formatting}"
  - posts.each do |post|
    = render post # or whatever you want
```